# Add x=y (45 degree) line within matplotlib axis limits

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot with different x- and y-limits:

```
fig, ax = subplots(ncols=1)
ax.set_xlim([0, 10])
ax.set_ylim([5, 10])
```

I would like to add an `x=y` line to this plot, but keep the line within the axis limits.

My first, naive attempt is just

```
ax.plot(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_xlim())
```

[image: First, naive attempt]

An improved attempt works, but is incredibly ugly, code-wise:

```
ax.plot([max(ax.get_xlim()[0], ax.get_ylim()[0]), 
         min(ax.get_xlim()[1], ax.get_ylim()[1])],
        [max(ax.get_xlim()[0], ax.get_ylim()[0]), 
         min(ax.get_xlim()[1], ax.get_ylim()[1])])
```

[image]

Is there a nicer way?
I'm using IPython version `1.2.1` inside Spyder `2.2.5` on Matplotlib version `1.3.1` and `mpl.get_backend()` returns:

```
'module://IPython.kernel.zmq.pylab.backend_inline'
```

Comment: Using your "first, naive attempt", I got the desired result. I wasn't able able to reproduce the line below the x-axis. What matplotlib version and backend are you using? Have you tried using `ax.plot(ax.get_ylim(), ax.get_ylim())`?

Comment: This works: `ax.plot(ax.get_ylim(), ax.get_ylim())`. Am I suffering some kind of weirdness with my version of mpl?

Comment: That's the same Matplotlib version and backend that I'm using, so I'm not sure what's going on. What version of IPython are you using?

Comment: I've updated the question with my IPython version.

Comment: @LondonRob - Your first method should have worked if the axes' "adjustable" style is set to "datalim", but it won't otherwise.  For it to work in general, try doing `ax.plot(ax.get_xlim(), ax.get_ylim(), clip_on=True, scalex=False, scaley=False)`.

Comment: @JoeKington I'm starting to think this is some kind of Spyder weirdness, because I can't reproduce the problem in IPython notebook with an identical setup and the same backend. If someone would be kind enough to reproduce this I'll submit a bug.

Comment: @LondonRob - I can't reproduce it.  Initially I thought you had set the aspect ratio and were getting odd interactions with the adjustable parameter, but that's not the case... Does explicitly specifying `clip_on`, `scalex`, and `scaley` fix the problem on your setup?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## In matplotlib <= 3.2

```
x = np.linspace(*ax.get_xlim())
ax.plot(x, x)
```

## In matplotlib >= 3.3

matplotlib 3.3 added the function `ax.axline`, which can do this better and still works if the axes limits are changed:

```
ax.axline([0, 0], [1, 1])
```

Comment: This produces the same result as my naive attempt. Note that I've updated the question with my matplotlib version and backend details.

Comment: I don't think matplotlib should even be able to plot something outside of the axes, you should fill in a bug report.

Comment: @MaxNoe - The `clip_on` kwarg controls that. Somehow `clip_on=False` is being used as the default with his setup.

Comment: ax.axline([0, 0], [1, 1]) is not even working. Please.

Answer (score 7):

If `0 <= X <= 1` and `0 <= Y <= 1`, this works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(X, Y)
plt.plot([0, 1], [0, 1], color = 'black', linewidth = 2)
plt.xlim(-0.05, 1.05)
plt.ylim(-0.05, 1.05)
```

You could adjust the limits, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Another appraoch.

```
xpoints = ypoints = plt.xlim()
plt.plot(xpoints, ypoints, linestyle='--', color='k', lw=3, scalex=False, scaley=False)
```

[Source](https://newbedev.com/makeing-a-45-degree-line-on-plot-plot-python-code-example)